# Problems with dplyr and POSIXlt data

Tags: r, dplyr, posixlt

I have a problem. I downloaded data and tranformed dates into POSIXlt format

```
df<-read.csv("007.csv", header=T, sep=";")
df$transaction_date<-strptime(df$transaction_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
df$install_date<-strptime(df$install_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
df$days<- as.numeric(difftime(df$transaction_date,df$install_date, units = "days"))
```

Data frame is about transaction in one online game. It contains value (its payment), transaction_date, intall_date and ID. I added new column, which showndays after installation. I tried to summarise data using dlyr

`df2<-df %>%
  group_by(days) %>%
  summarise(sum=sum(value))`

And I've got an error:
Error: column 'transaction_date' has unsupported type : POSIXlt, POSIXt

How can i Fix it?

UPD. I changed classes of Date columns into Character. It solved problem. But can i use dlyr withouts changing classes in my dataset?

Comment: use `POSIXct` instead

Comment: What eddi said... wrap `as.POSIXct` around the strptime calls.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `as.POSIXct` as recommended in the comments but if the hours, minutes, and seconds don't matter then you should just use `as.Date`

```
df <- read.csv("007.csv", header=T, sep=";")

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
     transaction_date = as.Date(transaction_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
     ,install_date = as.Date(install_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
  ) %>%
  group_by(days = transaction_date - install_date) %>%
  summarise(sum=sum(value))
```

Answer (score 7):

As noted [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/179), this is a "feature" of the tidyverse.  They don't want to handle `POSIXlt` object because it is some kind of list within a vector.  However, using `as.POSIXct` isn't always an option. In my case I really needed the `POSIXlt` class to handle some uncleaned data.  In that case, just go back to good old stable base R.  In your case:

```
df2 <- aggregate(df1$value, by=list(df$days), sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick I use often is the following:

1. Convert `POSIXt` columns (in example below `eventDate`) to character
2. Perform dplyr operations you need (in example below we bind rows of two data frames)
3. Convert back from character to `POSIXt` not forgetting to set the right format (`format`) and timezone (`tz`) as it was before performing step 1.

Example:

```
# step 1
df1$eventDate <- as.character.POSIXt(df1$eventDate)
df2$eventDate <- as.character.POSIXt(df2$eventDate)
#step 2
merged_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
#step 3
merged_df$eventDate <- strptime(merged_df$eventDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
```