# How to plot a count of N/As over time in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with dates in one field and N/As in another. I created this as a subset of a larger dataset because I need to see whether the number of N/As are from one time period or more evenly distributed across all time.

my data looks like this:

```
User_id |    Date    | app_version
001     | 2016-01-03 | <NA>
002     | 2016-03-03 | <NA>
003     | 2016-02-22 | <NA>
004     | 2016-04-15 | <NA>
...
```

What I'd like to do is plot a line graph with time on the X axis and number of NAs on the Y axis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your data first, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(app_version = sum(is.na(app_version))) %>% ggplot(aes(Date, app_version)) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`: Group your data accordingly, summarize and count the number of NA values, then plot.  (In this case, I grouped by `Date` and added `geom_point` to show each date.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarize(na_count = sum(is.na(app_version))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = na_count)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i'm getting this error message: `Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `install_date` is of unsupported class POSIXlt/POSIXt`

Comment: Sounds like you need to properly format `install_date`, try using `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063190/problems-with-dplyr-and-posixlt-data

Comment: Thanks, I was using `as.POSIXct()` but on the the wrong df :S. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your db

```
User_id<-c("001","002","003","004")
Date<-c("2016-01-03","2016-03-03","2016-02-22","2016-04-15")
app_version<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA)

db<-data.frame(cbind(User_id,Date,app_version))
```

Your graph

```
plot(table(db[is.na(db$app_version),"Date"]),type="l")
```

[image: Your plot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm getting this error: `Error in table(na_df[is.na(na_df$app_version), "install_date"]) : 
  'names' attribute [75] must be the same length as the vector [11]`

Comment: Please, add more details about the code generating thies error

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
#create a field that breaks the dates down to just year & month
#You can break it down by year if you'd like
df$yr_mth<-substr(df$Date, 1, 7)
#summarize the number of NAs per year_month 
df1<-ddply(df, .(yr_mth), summarize, 
    num_na=length(which(is.na(app_version))))
#plot yr_mth on x, num_na on y
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=as.Date(yr_mth), y=num_na))+
    geom_point()
```